# How do I set the element's type of an HtmlElement?

Tags: c#, html, .net

I'm so befuddled that I can't find in the [documentation on HtmlElement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlelement(v=vs.110).aspx) how to set the type of the element. For example, I say I want

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com">Here's the coolest site ever.</a>
```

Where do I set the fact that it's an `a` that I want?

```
var mytag = new HtmlElement() { InnerText = "Here's the coolest site ever." };
mytag.SetAttribute("href", "http://stackoverflow.com");
mytag.WhatDoIPutHere = "a";
```

Comment: Hey!! @steve did u tried the solution I suggested. Does it helped you?

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation, it says:

> Provides programmatic access to the document's  element on the server, which represents the document's root.

Which means that `HtmlElement` is going to generate a `<html />` tag - that is - it's *not* a generic element. You'd want to use [`HtmlAnchor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlanchor(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [HtmlTextWriter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmltextwriter(v=vs.110).aspx) instead

```
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();

// Put HtmlTextWriter in using block because it needs to call Dispose.
using (HtmlTextWriter writer = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
{
    writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Href, "http://stackoverflow.com");
    writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.A); 
    writer.Write("Here's the coolest site ever.");
    writer.RenderEndTag(); 
}
```